# New job - HR Assistant

Tags: new-job, career-development

What can you do to explain to the overall manager that the work you are completing is not stretching or developing you. I accepted a role and have been working for the last month. I have the role of 'Assistant' yet I feel like a glorified Administrator. I have a degree in HR and I am Level 5 CIPD qualified, yet I am not being used to my capability. All I seem to be doing is data entry, printing & filing.

Comment: Please bear in mind that very few advanced position is offered to fresh out of academy graduates. You've only been in your current role for a month, give it some patience, show not only your ambition but also your capacity to your employer, and see if things gets better after at least half or a whole year.

Comment: Question, can you land a different position with more responsibility in your current state of education / experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hard truth to accept is, employers are paying you because you complete work for them. They're not paying you to be stretched, or to develop you. While many employers try very hard to support employee development, the primary reason they pay you, as an employee, is to do the work that they choose to assign to you.

If you find that work unacceptable, you can always take steps to try to address that. But a good rule of thumb in the work place is: before you ask for anything special, or additional, or new, *make sure you have things in order with respect to your current responsibilities.* Do you complete your work on time, with high quality? Do you present yourself as helpful and positive? If an employee asks for additional work, or harder work, and their boss thinks that they have issues even managing their current workload, or they're lazy, or whatever - that won't end well.

Once you're sure you understand your current tasks and are doing quality work, you can certainly approach your boss. If you have a specific task you wish you were doing, you could ask something along the lines of,

> Hey boss, I've been wondering if there are any opportunities for me to help with X?

Or, if there's a specific issue you wish you could tackle,

> Hey boss, I noticed problem Y, can I spend some time working on that?

Or, if you want to be more strategic,

> Hey boss, I was wondering if we could set aside some time to talk about potential future opportunities here - I'd like to understand how ACME Co. supports growth of their employees.

By asking in this manner, you can present yourself as **looking for opportunities to be helpful,** instead of presenting yourself as someone who thinks they are overqualified or otherwise above their current job.

It's also worth considering that employment is a long term relationship. One month isn't much of a history to base an employer on, in terms of complexity of tasks or future growth. It may be that this is their natural busy season, or there's a distraction that has kept them from spending more time getting you involved, or some other factor you're not aware of.

And, at the end of the day, if your current employer simply doesn't have any "harder" work to give you, you may just have to accept that fact, and choose whether you will remain employed by them or look for another opportunity. But keep in mind, pretty much all jobs will have at least *some* tasks that are not glorious or rewarding in some way. Learning to deal with tedious work can be helpful even as you climb to more ambitious positions.

As a final thought, if you *do* consider this a terminal problem, and you decide to look for employment elsewhere, **make sure you incorporate your lessons learned into your job search.** Interviews are two-way: the employer is evaluating you, but you need to evaluate them - and the job. Make sure you understand what drives you, and ask questions that help you understand if a potential new employer would be a good fit. If you need to be "pushed" or you like certain types of work, or you like an environment that's constantly changing and challenges you, think of (positive) questions to ask along those lines.